# How to increase GAE datastore index quota?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm almost at the limit of 200. I thought there used to be a form to request an increase of quota beyond 200, but it looks like that link is gone now. All I see is a generic feature request link on this page:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Datastore

Comment: Seems they want to push you to premium accuonts :/

Comment: That's what it seems. I'm hoping for a happier answer.

Comment: Have you taken the premium account? Were you able to increase your quota?

Comment: I did sign up for premium support (150 per month), but I have not requested yet a quota increase. I ended up figuring out how to cut my indexes in 1/2 by re-designing some stuff. I will likely need to request an increase in the future, and I'm pretty sure Google will grant an increase if you have premium support.